# Prove $\mathbf{1}_{A_i}=\sum_{j}\mathbf{1}_{A_i\cap B_j}$

Tags: real-analysis

How can i prove this: $\mathbf{1}_{A_i}=\sum_{j}\mathbf{1}_{A_i\cap B_j}$ ?

By definition, the indicator function

$$\boldsymbol{1}_{A_i}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \in A_i \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Moreover,

$$\boldsymbol{1}_{A_i\cap B_j}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \in A_i\cap B_j \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

I'm stuck, can someone help me?

Comment: Please be more specific, what is the relation between the set $A_{i}$ and $B_{j}$ here

Comment: This is not true in general. You need to tell us the definitions of $B_j$'s.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2747429/expressing-the-sum-of-two-simple-functions of this exercise @Izstat

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2747429/expressing-the-sum-of-two-simple-functions @EvanWilliamChandra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that $A \subset X$ and $\{B_{j}\}_{j}$ is a partition of $X$

i.e. $X = \cup_{j}B_{j}$, and $B_{j}\cap B_{k} = \emptyset$ if $j \not= k$

Now, let $x \in X$, then $x\in B_{k}$ for some and only one $k$

Then, if $x\notin A$ then $x \notin A\cap B_{j} \forall j$

Thus $\sum_{j}1_{A\cap B_{j}}(x) = \sum_{j}0 = 0 = 1_{A}(x)$

If $x \in A$, then $x\in A\cap B_{k}$ and $x \notin A\cap B_{j}$ for all $j\not= k$

Thus $\sum_{j} 1_{A\cap B_{j}}(x) = 1_{A\cap B_{k}}(x) = 1 = 1_{A}(x)$

Then $1_{A}(x) = \sum_{j}1_{A\cap B_{j}}(x)$ for all $x \in X$

I hope this can help you